# Load testing an ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I want to load test an ASP.NET web service.  I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition and Visual Studio 2010.

Can either one of these products facilitate load testing?  I can't seem to find anything and all Google returns is higher end editions of Visual Studio.

If not, what are some of the alternatives.

Or better yet, is there a product where I can feed it an IIS log and it will essentially replay it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Is there a cheaper way to do load testing than upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102378/is-there-a-cheaper-way-to-do-load-testing-than-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2010-ul)
and also there was a tool called "MICROSOFT WEB APPLICATION STRESS TOOL" but i couldnt find its download apperantely MS removed it from its official page. check this forum for download link http://forums.iis.net/t/1161284.aspx for usage http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/webstress/webstress.htm

Answer (score 6):

There is a free Microsoft load testing tool called [WCAT](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1466). It is a command-line HTTP load generator that replays a test case script. To avoid creating the script manually, you can record your test case in Fiddler and then generate scrip using WCAT Fiddler Extension. This [blog](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/05/11/using-the-wcat-fiddler-extension-for-web-server-performance-tests.aspx) has a step-by-step instruction, which I tested, and it works.

On your question about replaying IIS log: check [this](http://theether.net/kb/100128) source. It outlines how to generate WCAT script by querying IIS log using Log Parser. I did not test it though.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Test Edition would also give you access to these tools. Unfortunately neither of the tools you mention include any load testing capability.

You may be able to get your licence for 2008 Professional edition changed to Test, but I doubt it now.

Here are a couple of other questions with answers that may help choose a tool.

1. [stress-and-performance-test-on-asp-net-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632036/stress-and-performance-test-on-asp-net-app)
2. [best-tool-for-performance-testing-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867/best-tool-for-performance-testing-asp-net)
3. [how-to-set-up-a-load-stress-test-for-a-web-site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834194/how-to-set-up-a-load-stress-test-for-a-web-site)